# How to calculate separate average by groups in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, average, dax

I am trying to calculate average for different companies. Different average value for each company.
But it's calculating for each row(?). For example, For  one company we have 6 values: 5,0,0,5,0,0. 
Logically, average EQ to 1.7
Power BI shows 5.

I grouped each company to make it easier to calculate the amount and divide by the number of cells belonging to each value. Also, I did it directly through AVERAGEX, and also, through the AVERAGE(CALCULATE - SUM).

```
"NEW COLUMN NAME" = AVERAGE(KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table1'[Contractor(groups)])),CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table1'[Event Identification])))
```

I expect: 5,0,0,5,0,0 = 1.7
And calculations (output) will be provided for each group.

Comment: Can you add your `GroupBy` formula in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I will be able to give you a better answer if I can see how yo grouped it.

But I tried AVERAGEX in one of my tables, and its working fine. Below if the formula:

```
=GROUPBY('Table','Table'[Column1],"ABC",AVERAGEX(CURRENTGROUP(),'Table'[Amount]))
```